# Programmatically adding a Panel control adds "body" to its ID

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

So I have this code:

```
var pnl = new Panel() {
    CssClass = "tab-pane",
    ID = "tab_content_" + gymTypes.Rows[0]["stars"].ToString()
};
tab_content.Controls.Add(pnl);
```

The `gymTypes.Rows[0]["stars"]` returns 1 so the ID should be `tab_content_1` however when I run the website and inspect element the ID is somehow `body_tab_content_1`.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I know web forms does some funny things with the id's of controls. Do you have it nested in another control with the Id of body?

Comment: did you look at the ClientID of the object in the debugger.  This is what is written to the HTML page.

Comment: @Hogan Yup, the ClientID is as expected `tab_content_1`

Comment: @Aaron The body tag is within the master page, I have no other elements with the id of body

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET changes the ID of your elements. It is a documented behavior. If you need the id to stay the same, you need to set the [ClientIDMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) attribute of your panel

Comment: If ClientIDMode doesn't accept a string how else am I suppose to add the ID?

Comment: You still set the id. then you just set the ClientIDmode to static. so asp know that it shouldn't change what you wrote in the id field. The Client ID mode tell asp how to handle what you put in the ID FIeld.